# Is learning JavaFX before using FXML neccessary?

Tags: javafx, fxml

Do any developers use JavaFX alone over an FXML?

The benefits are obvious and of course knowing what the layout does is helpful. So I am wondering if there is any reason to learn about how the placement works and how everything works together behind the scenes of an FXML, as if I were to hard code it all?

I am trying to self teach myself somethings and I don't want to "half-ass" it. I coded very little in JavaFX, and used an FXML once, but if no one codes in JavaFX alone (or if there is any point to), maybe I'll just skip the process of learning about the code itself and jump right into the FXML

Comment: It's not clear what this question means. FXML is part of JavaFX, and is essentially just an alternative way to create and configure objects. How would you know what to put in the FXML file if you didn't "learn JavaFX"?

Comment: I edited it, I hope it is a bit clearer.

Comment: You're creating a false dichotomy. You can't understand one without the other (if there's even any difference between the two). "Learning JavaFX" means learning about how layouts work, how the application should be structured, what API classes are available and what they do. Which particular choice of syntax you use is a minor detail, and you can't really understand either one properly without the other imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is possible to use JavaFX without FMXL!

But if you want to use FXML you could take a look at the **Scene-Builder**. Could be very useful and save you some time because you don't have to write all the FMXL yourself.

This thread should kind of answer your question too:
[Java FX: declarative vs procedural](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161781/java-fx-declarative-vs-procedural)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response!

I meant more, is it worth trying to code in JavaFX before using the FXML which will do most of the work for you anyways?

I am trying to self teach myself somethings and I don't want to "half-ass" it. I coded very little in JavaFX, and used an FXML once, but if no one codes in JavaFX alone (or if there is any point to), maybe I'll just skip the process of learning about the code itself and jump right into the FXML.

Comment: Like James_D said. It is actually necessary to know both. But it's totally up to you how you end up realising your project. Both techniques have advantages and disadvantages.